# Converting cmake project to qmake

Tags: cmake, qmake

I am trying to convert a rather simple CMakeLists.txt to a qmake project. The project compiles fine but I can't get the output I want (the program files are the same!).

It shouldn't be a big deal, but I have spent the whole day and can't seem to figure out the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the CMakeLists.txt that I am trying to convert:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6) 
PROJECT (sdpwrapper) 

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3")
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O3")

ADD_LIBRARY(objdettrack 
    ./src/MyPipe.cpp 
    ./src/SDPWrapper.cpp 
    ./src/online_tracker.cpp
    ./src/BaseObjectTracker2D.cpp)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(include 
    /usr/include/python2.7 
    ../dep/NOMT/include/ 
    ../dep/NOMT/dep/eigen/ 
    ../dep/NOMT/dep/libDAI-0.3.2/include/)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(objdettrack
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/../dep/NOMT/lib/libcppmodule.so
    python2.7
    ${OpenCV_LIBS})

ADD_EXECUTABLE(example ./src/main.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(example objdettrack)

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenMP)
IF(OPENMP_FOUND)
  SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
  SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS}")
  SET(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${OpenMP_C_FLAGS}")
ENDIF()
```

and here's the qmake project file I created:

```
QT       += widgets

TARGET = ./build/DummyProject
#CONFIG   += console
#CONFIG   -= app_bundle

SOURCES += ./src/main.cpp \
    ./src/MyPipe.cpp \
    ./src/online_tracker.cpp \
    ./src/SDPWrapper.cpp \
    ./src/BaseObjectTracker2D.cpp

TEMPLATE = app
#TEMPLATE += lib



# ZEESHAN:INTEGRATION CODE
INCLUDEPATH += ./include
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/python2.7 
INCLUDEPATH += /home/ma/zeeshan/code/Joint/KITTI_Jun2016/slam/app/faster-rcnn/dep/NOMT/include/ 
INCLUDEPATH += /home/ma/zeeshan/code/Joint/KITTI_Jun2016/slam/app/faster-rcnn/dep/NOMT/dep/eigen/ 
INCLUDEPATH += /home/ma/zeeshan/code/Joint/KITTI_Jun2016/slam/app/faster-rcnn/dep/NOMT/dep/libDAI-0.3.2/include/

QMAKE_LIBDIR += /home/ma/zeeshan/code/Joint/KITTI_Jun2016/slam/app/faster-rcnn/dep/NOMT/lib
LIBS += -lcppmodule
LIBS += -lpython2.7
LIBS += -lpynomt

QMAKE_LIBDIR += ../../faster-rcnn/cpp/lib
LIBS += -Lobjdettrack

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -fopenmp
QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -fopenmp
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Zeeshan

Comment: Why would you even do that? Projects should be moved from qmake to CMake.

Comment: I agree with @Velkan, Qt support `CMake` nowadays. I'd like to know an easy way to translate from `qmake` to `CMake`...